# Getting “Open the GPS power failure” on module SIM808

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, tinygps, error, sim808

I tried to get the gps coordinates with this program:

```
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define PIN_TX    8
#define PIN_RX    7
SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_RX,PIN_TX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);//Connect RX,TX,PWR,

//DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&Serial);

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //******** Initialize sim808 module *************
  while(!sim808.init()) { 
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("Sim808 init error\r\n");
  }


  //************* Turn on the GPS power************
  if( sim808.attachGPS())
      Serial.println("Open the GPS power success");
  else 
      Serial.println("Open the GPS power failure");
  
}

void loop() {
   //************** Get GPS data *******************
   if (sim808.getGPS()) {
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.year);
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.month);
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.day);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.hour);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.minute);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.second);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.centisecond);
    Serial.print("latitude :");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lat);
    Serial.print("longitude :");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lon);
    Serial.print("speed_kph :");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.speed_kph);
    Serial.print("heading :");
    Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.heading);
    Serial.println();

    //************* Turn off the GPS power ************
    sim808.detachGPS();
  }

}
```

But when I run it, I'm getting the "Open the GPS power failure" message.

I think my gps is working because If I try with AT commands Im getting a response:

```
 AT+CGPSSTATUS?
+CGPSSTATUS: Location 3D Fix

OK
AT+CGPSINF=0
+CGPSINF: 0,2543.585143,10018.826326,483.868110,20221118025902.000,19,10,0.509509,266.733459

OK
```

I even tried to get NMEA info and parse that in python, I was getting my actual position so it seems is working properly.

The problem comes when I tried to use DFRobot_sim808 library or TinyGps libraries.

I would like to know what might be causing this issue or is there a way to parse NMEA info coordinates without using a library?

Comment: this may help ... https://www.gpsworld.com/what-exactly-is-gps-nmea-data/

Comment: are you at a library in Monterrey?

Comment: Yeah... I was there. How did you get the location? I know I gave them but I want to know how you translate or parse that raw gps info

Comment: I parsed the NMEA sentence ... 2543.585143,10018.826326 is the latitude and longitude ... 25 degrees 43.585143 minutes ... 100 degrees 18.826326 minutes .... that is 25.72641905, 100.3147721 degrees .... 25°43'35.1"N 100°18'53.2"W
https://goo.gl/maps/2UV2g2qouJ2uWhJaA

Comment: Okey I understand that you are parsing coordinates in DDDMM.MMMM to a more readible format. But how are you doing that? Are you using a formula, a software, a library or what? I want to know that because I need to capture that info through code

Comment: pencil and paper  ... convert degrees and minutes to decimal degrees

Comment: Okey, you really gave me enough to work with. Thank you :)